# What is the difference between jface treeviewer setComparer method and setSorter method?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jface

Could anyone explain me conceptually(inner working), what is the difference between  jface `treeviewer` `setComparer` method and `setSorter` method.

Comment: Conceptual questions should be asked on [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Are you looking to understand how the library's source code works, or are you looking to understand the differences between them so you can choose which of them to use in your own code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setSorter` is an obsolete method which has been replaced by `setComparator`.

The `ViewerSorter` class used by `setSorter` only supported the use of a `Collator` for sorting.

The `ViewerComparator` class used by `setComparator` supports any `Comparator` class.

The `IElementComparer` class set by the `setComparer` method is used when the viewer is searching its internal `HashMap` for matching elements (such as when you call `refresh(element)`). Sometimes the `equals` and `hashCode` methods on the actual object are not be suitable for this lookup so you can use the `IElementComparer` to provide alternatives.

So the `setComparer` is not used for sorting the view like the `setSorter` or `setComparator` methods.

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for your quick response , but i wanted to know about setComparer and not setComparator. Forgive me if iam wrong some where .

Comment: Sorry, added extra info